# Is $return variable anyhow special in Perl?

Tags: perl

We have observed strange effects when using `$return` variable in code like `$return = foo($something);`. Is `$return` variable somehow special because of the **return** name?

Comment: what are these strange effects ?

Comment: Mm, delicious tasty vagueness!

Comment: The only special variables in Perl are listed in `perldoc perlvar`. Other than those, you can use any name you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), no.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not [perl special](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). But some module my export it and this may provide unexpected behavior.

see [This tutorial](http://stein.cshl.org/genome_informatics/using_perl_modules/export.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about a variable named `$return`. That said, writing

```
my $return = foo($something);
return $return;
```

is not the same as writing

```
return foo($something);
```

The first form puts the call to `foo()` in scalar context. The latter will propagate the context from the caller. This could cause `foo()` to behave differently. Compare:

```
sub foo { return localtime }
sub bar { my $x = foo(); return $x }
sub baz { return foo() }

say join ', ', bar(); # Thu May 26 08:24:59 2011
say join ', ', baz(); # 59, 24, 8, 26, 4, 111, 4, 145, 1
```

This happens because in scalar context, `localtime` returns the time formatted as a string but in list context it returns a list of values for seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

The concept of context is unique to Perl. To learn more about it, see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: not only that, but the last line of a sub will be the return value if no return is specified. Therefore `sub bar { $x = foo() }` is the same as your `bar`, as is `sub bar { scalar foo() }` or `sub bar { return scalar foo() }`.

Comment: @Joel: [nit] In the absence of an explicit `return` a sub returns the value of the last *expression*. While that's usually the last line of the sub it doesn't have to be.